# React native connect to local database with php and axios

Tags: php, react-native, axios, localhost

I'm having a problem connecting the front-end to the back-end through PHP. The database is connected with PHP but not the front-end, and when I run it on the Postman, it prints out 500 internal server error.

```
    axios
      .get(Api, {
        params: {
          route: "extension/account/purpletree_multivendor/api/sellers",
          language_id: this.props.language,
          search_text: this.state.searchTxt.toUpperCase(),
          category_id: categoryId.toString(),
          geocode: geocode,
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //handle no seach item
        if (res.data.success) {
          if (res.data.message !== "No Data") {
            this.setState({
              sellers: res.data.data.sellers,
              isLoading: false,
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, showMessage: true });
          }
        } else {
          //show error message
          this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
      });
```

Comment: try to add your PHP code

Comment: so the issue is in your backend if you can't get a 200 from postman

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve 500 Internal Server Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864905/how-to-resolve-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @KartikChauhan 500 internal server error is a generic error, the best way to do is to print out the specific error, it should show the specific error in postman or browser, if it doesn't show, then go find out the PHP version you are using first, then get into the php.ini, make display_errors = true, it should print out the actual errors. In my case, it's because the database is not fully built in the local, that's why the 500 internal error shows.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering this question, I have asked an instructor of mine and figured:

1. I did not turn on the `display_errors` in php.ini
2. After turning it on it prints out the detailed error, which is some of my database tables are missing, so it won't be able to run.